# How make query and show data

Tags: php, forms, input, numbers, integer

I try to do input number form and make search in page grapht.php. For example I write code:

```
<form action="grapht.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="number" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="submit">        
    </td>
</form>
<? $number= $_POST["number"]; ?>
```

And then make query my MySQL table:

```
$shipmin = 1;
$shipmax=$number;
$uzklausimas ="SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE id >= '$shipmin' AND id<= '$shipmax'";
$minmax=mysqli_query($conn,$uzklausimas);

while($ru=mysqli_fetch_assoc($minmax)){
    echo "$ru[id] <br>";
}
```

But my code doesn't work. Maybe somebody could give me advice how need solve this my problem?

Comment: _"But my code don't work"_ - In what way? Error messages? Checked servers error log? Wrong result? Computer catches fire?

Comment: You should use `<?php` instead of `<?` when opening PHP blocks. You should also look into using Prepared Statements instead of inserting unescaped user data in your query, which opens you up for SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you initialize your db connection ($conn) before this line ?

```
$minmax=mysqli_query($conn,$uzklausimas);
```

Comment: if I write line $shipmax=45; it is working well, but if I write $shipmax=$number; It is not work

Comment: Check the content of your $_POST variable with a var_dump. If it's empty, your problem is in your form. Can you post all the script ?

Comment: I give all the script in the top

Answer (score 0):

if I write line `$shipmax=45;` it is working well, but I have static date from 1 to 45. If I write `$shipmax=$number;` It is not work.

Answer (score 0):

all my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$shipmin = 1;
$shipmax=$number;

$uzklausimas ="SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE id >= '$shipmin' AND id<='$number'";
$minmax=mysqli_query($conn,$uzklausimas);


while($ru=mysqli_fetch_assoc($minmax)){
    echo "$ru[id] <br>";    
} 


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
   <form action="forum.php" method="post">
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off"><br>
       <input type="submit">        
        </td></form>

       <? $number= (int)$_POST["name"]; ?>
    <?php echo $number; ?>
<br>
```

Page where you could see it is http://ortex.lt/forum.php